# How do a turn a generics based method into a lambda with Func<...>

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

How do a turn this

```
public static List<T> CreateListOfAnonymous<T>(T unused) {return new List<T>();}
```

into a lamda. I just can't seem to work it out. as a generic of a generic gives an error

i.e:

```
Func<T,T> ..... fails because its looking for a real type.
```

My goal is to use the logic from that method above, but without a method, just internally inside some method.

Comment: It's not clear how you're trying to use this. Please give some more sample code of what you're trying to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My goal is to use the logic from that method above, but without a method, just internally inside some method.

If the method or type you're using the lambda in is generic (so that you have a type that is concrete in-context) then you can get this to work:

```
public void SomeMethod<T>()
{
    Func<T, List<T>> createList = CreateListOfAnonymous;
    var list = createList(default(T));
}

// ...

class SomeClass<T>
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        Func<T, List<T>> createList = CreateListOfAnonymous;
        var list = createList(default(T));
    }
}
```

If neither is true for your code, or you want to keep `T` for the lambda as an open generic (potentially of some other type than the method or class's generic parameters), then it won't be possible, [as leppie mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8531283/232593).

I've found in cases where I've wanted to do this type of thing in the past (to [avoid repeating myself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)), I only had a few types I wanted to bind to in the method.  So I just bit the bullet and created one concrete version for each type I wanted to support:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    Func<List<string>> createStringList = () => CreateListOfAnonymous("");
    Func<List<int>> createIntList = () => CreateListOfAnonymous(0);

    var list1 = createStringList();
    var list2 = createStringList();
    var list3 = createStringList();
    var list4 = createIntList();
    var list5 = createIntList();

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> How do I turn a generic method into a lambda?

You don't. Lambdas cannot be generic. Sorry! That's one of the differences between nominal and anonymous functions; anonymous functions cannot be generic, nominal ones can.

Can you explain what is the scenario that is requiring generic anonymous methods? If there is a really good reason to add this to the language, we could consider it for a hypothetical future version.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, it is not possible.

You cannot have instances of open generic types.